# Angularjs:call method from controller in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controller - controller1 and controller2.

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {

$scope.setItems=function()
{
    var itemName='Lemon';
}

});

app.controller('Controller2', function($scope) {
     //This controller i want da get 'itemName' from 'controller1'
});
```

How  to get Data from controller2 to controller1.
I apologize that my example is simple, but I want to figure it out

Comment: Ideally for this kind of situation, you should create service/factory to share data between two controllers

Comment: If your no problem, please example!

Comment: ok, controller to controller isnt valid from pattern , for you issue , you can use , factorys, services, rootscope, localstorage,  $swatch, $.emit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Controllers, as a rule, should not be aware of anything other than the objects they, themselves, are manipulating. Services are what allows your application to pass objects between controllers, as services persist through the application, where controllers are destroyed and re-started on a repeated basis.

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['ItemService1',function($scope, itemService) {

$scope.setItems=function()
{
    var itemName='Lemon';
   itemService.AddItem(itemName);
}

}]);

app.controller('Controller2', ['ItemService1', function($scope, itemService) {
     //This controller i want da get 'itemName' from 'controller1'
var lemons = itemService.getLemons();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

its a bad design to be in one controller and access variables or methods in another controller. You can use services to do this job. Assign data to services so it can be share/access by multiple controllers/services in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Angular `controller` can't share state with another `controller` unless you inject it somehow. Generally for sharing controllers state it is best practice to use `factory`, `service` or `$rootScope` in this exact order.